# Defining Python class instance attributes

Tags: python, class, properties, getter-setter

Given a class definition that allows 3 possible inputs:

```
class FooBar(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None, z=None):
        if x is not None:
            self.x = x
        elif if y is not None:
            self.y = y
        elif if z is not None:
            self.z = z
        else:
            raise ValueError('Please supply either x,y or z')
```

This 3 inputs are related each other, lets say:

`x = .5*y = .25*z`

This also implies:

`y = .5*z = 2*x`

and

`z = 2*y = 4*x`

When creating a instance of `FooBar()`, the user need to supply one of those and the `__init__` takes care of it.

Now I would like to do the following

- If any one of the 3 variables are changed the others change following the relationship.

To try to accomplish that I did:

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x

@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    self._x = value
    self._y = 2*self._x
    self._z = 4*self._x
```

And to the others:

```
@property
def y(self):
    return self._y

@y.setter
def y(self, value):
    self._y = value
    self._x = .5*self._y
    self._z = 2*self._y

@property
def z(self):
    return self._z

@z.setter
def z(self, value):
    self._z = value
    self._x = .25*self._z
    self._y = .5*self._z
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: What if I provide `FooBar(x=1, y=1425)`?

Comment: If `x = 2*y`, then `self._y = value/2` for the setter of `x`. Not `value * 2`.

Comment: Based on my `__init__`, `x` takes precedence, that is the reason to be and `if elif...`.

Comment: ok. I did the opposite, you're right. But I'm more worried about the instance variable setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make this more complicated than you have to. If the variables are related, and one can fully be determined by the other, there is no need to store three variables. You can store one variable, and dynamically calculate the others. Like:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None, z=None):
        if x is not None:
            self.x = x
        elif x is not None:
            self.y = y
        elif z is not None:
            self.z = z
        else:
            raise ValueError('Provide an x, y, or z value.')

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._x / 2.0

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._x = 2 * value

    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._x / 4.0

    @z.setter
    def z(self, value):
        self._x = 4 * value
```

We thus store only a `_x` attribute on the class, and all the rest of the getters and setters, use the `_x` attribute (we can of course use `_y` or `_z` instead).

Furthermore something that is not very elegant is that a programmer can instantiate a `Foo(x=1, y=425)`. As you can see, that means that it contains inconsistency. Perhaps it is worth raising an error in that case.

You can ensure that you only have one parameter provided by adding the following check in the init module:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None, z=None):
        data = [i for i in [x, y, z] if i is not None]
        if len(data) > 1:
            raise ValueError('Multiple parameters provided.')
        if x is not None:
            self.x = x
        elif x is not None:
            self.y = y
        elif z is not None:
            self.z = z
        else:
            raise ValueError('Provide an x, y, or z value.')

    # ...
```

Here we thus construct a list of all non-`None` values, if there is more than one, the programmer provided two or more values, and then it is better to raise an exception.

Comment: To avoid the " inconsistency", is a simple matter to add more conditions on `if`  clauses as: `if x is not None and y is None and z is None: `. And do the same to all other 2 cases, but this grows insanely (in case of more parameters). Any other elegant way to do this?

Comment: Good idea, did this way: `if sum(i is not None for i in locals().values()) > 2: raise ValueError("...")`. Thank you.